# Flickity - Increase sensitivity for drag/swipe trigger to next/prev slide

Tags: javascript, flickity

I'm looking for a way to adjust the sensitivity (or threshold) for swiping to the next/prev slide - for example, I'd like to be able to only swipe 2px left or right and release to move to the next/prev slide. Note that I'm not asking for the `dragThreshold` option, which adjusts when the horizontal swipe kicks in - I want to actually move to the next slide with less effort, such as on Patagonia's mobile site: https://www.patagonia.com/product/mens-pack-in-pullover-hoody/20895.html

- test that against https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html on mobile to see how much more stubborn flickity is before it swipes.

I can't find any examples of this, is there any way to do it outside of manually tracking drag direction and distance, and manually triggering an advance to the next or prev index? If that's the only way, can you share a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found some workaround?